# Open python script using command line

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, command-line

I created python script (**"hello.py"** for example).
But I would like to open script from any directory using:

```
darker0n@MacBook ~>hello
```

Comment: What do you mean? Use: `python /path/to/hello.py`

Comment: I don't want use this path. I want easy: hello

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a symbolic link in your `/usr/local/bin` folder (or any folder in your PATH env variable) with the command:

```
ln -s  /path/to/hello.py /usr/local/bin/hello
```

This will allow to keep your script in your preferred path and having the possibility to modify it anytime.

Comment: Messing with system directories like `/usr/bin` is almost never the right solution to a problem.

Comment: Yes ok /usr/bin is maybe not appropriate but any folder in the PATH can be used. Changed to /usr/local/bin in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom command that'll invoke your Python script.

Let's say your `hello.py` is in the path `/home/python/hello.py`

Create a custom script called `hello` containing:

`python /home/python/hello.py`.

You can put it a hidden directory so that it remains hidden.

Say you've added it to the following file: `/home/python/.custom/hello`. Now add the following line to your `.bashrc` (or equivalent) file:

`export PATH=$PATH":/home/python/.custom`

Next time you open a terminal and type `hello`, you get the script to run. To get it immediately in any already open terminal sessions, simply run `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: If the python script is named `hello` instead of `hello.py` and has an appropriate shebang (`#!`) line then the intermediate shell script is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use a shell interpreter line, (shebang line).  For example, in a file called hello.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
python code here
...
```

then

```
chmod +x hello
```

and put the hello script somewhere in your PATH.

Oh and don't type

```
~>hello
```

that is a syntax error, and the > will redirect output to a file hello, overwrite it with nothing, as the "~" is not really a command, but a special shell $HOME directory spec.  Unless the ~> is part of your prompt, then ignore this warning.